Very first android app, can not get it to build
I am trying to build my first android app using kotlin.
I am following the tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-android-app-amplify/ because i want this app to use aws AIM and S3
Following the tutorial there seems to be some differences with the tutorial and the version of android i am creating. I have tried to make the correct changes.
for example in the build.gradle I do not have
kotlin-android-extensions

because i have
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
} 

Where I am having issues is with MainActivity
The project does not know what toolbar
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

and item_list
setupRecyclerView(item_list)

I am getting Unresolved reference for both
Here is the entire file
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
//import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
//import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        // prepare our List view and RecyclerView (cells)
        setupRecyclerView(item_list)
    }

    // recycler view is the list of cells
    private fun setupRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {

        // update individual cell when the Note data are modified
        UserData.notes().observe(this, Observer<MutableList<UserData.Note>> { notes ->
           Log.d(TAG, "Note observer received ${notes.size} notes")

           // let's create a RecyclerViewAdapter that manages the individual cells
           recyclerView.adapter = NoteRecyclerViewAdapter(notes)
        })
    }

    companion object {
         private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }

  }

This is the build.gradle file
plugins {
     alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
     alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
     namespace 'com.example.framewithaws'
     compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.example.framewithaws"
         minSdk 24
         targetSdk 34
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"

         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
       viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
     implementation libs.aws.android.sdk.core
     implementation libs.aws.android.sdk.s3
     implementation libs.aws.android.sdk.mobile.client

     implementation libs.androidx.core.ktx
     implementation libs.androidx.appcompat
     implementation libs.material
     implementation libs.androidx.constraintlayout
     implementation libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx
     implementation libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx
     testImplementation libs.junit
     androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.junit
     androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.espresso.core
}

I am not sure if more info is needed.
I am a real noob at this and just want it to compile so i can start understanding.
Thanks for any help

If you are using view binding, did you follow this guide? You have not created the binding in your activity.

thanks to tomerpacific
I needed to add
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
        private lateinit var contentMainBinding: ContentMainBinding

Here is the entire file that now compiles
        class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
            private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
            private lateinit var contentMainBinding: ContentMainBinding
        
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
                binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
                setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        
                contentMainBinding = ContentMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);
                setupRecyclerView(contentMainBinding.itemList)
            }
        
            // recycler view is the list of cells
            private fun setupRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
                // update individual cell when the Note data are modified
                UserData.notes().observe(this, Observer<MutableList<UserData.Note>> { notes ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Note observer received ${notes.size} notes")
        
                    // let's create a RecyclerViewAdapter that manages the individual cells
                    recyclerView.adapter = NoteRecyclerViewAdapter(notes)
                })
            }
        
            companion object {
                private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
            }
        }

